# how to push [read more] button twice

Tags: html, css, text, checkbox, paragraph

I want to shrink my paragraph into a couple of *read more*, without the need to read less.
I only manage to do it once and 'm now lost.

```css
.bio {
  font-family: monospace;
}

#check {
  display: none;
}

#check:checked~.more {
  display: block;
}

.more {
  display: none;
}

label {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="bio">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  <p>craftsman</p> *original display*
  <div class="more">
    <p>since birth has always had a love/hate relationship</p> *first readmore*
  </div>
  <label for="check"> more</label>
  <div class="more">
    <p>She had half-survived blahblahblah.</p> *second readmore*
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need to solve it with CSS only? A JS solution would be more appropriate for productive sue. The issue is, that your read more button is a checkbox that only can have a checked or unchecked state. It will not keep increasing the readable text

Comment: yes i think ill switch to JS,
so it is possible with a JS solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make all elements with the class *more* hidden by using: `.more { display: none }`
2. Create a class to make elements visible again: `.d-block { display: block }`
3. Create a Node List in JS with all elements with the class *more*: `let bio_sections = document.querySelectorAll('.more')`
4. Create a variable at 0 as index: `let bio_index = 0`
5. Add a `click`-`eventListener` linked to the button: `button-element.addEventListener('click', () => { ... })`
6. Within the function create an `if`-condition to ensure that the actual function is only as often run as you have elements with the class *more*  as otherwise, you will create an error after every further button click: `if (bio_index < bio_sections.length)`
7. select the element out of the Node List with the current index: `bio_sections[bio_index]`
8. Add that previously created class to that element: `.classList.add('d-block')`
9. Increase the index to jump to the next element within your Node List: `bio_index++`

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.bio button');
let bio_sections = document.querySelectorAll('.bio .more');

/* index to iterate */
let bio_index = 0;

//trigger to check for button clicks
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // ensures JS errors as otherwise elements going to be called that does not exist
  if (bio_index < bio_sections.length) {
    // makes the section visible
    bio_sections[bio_index].classList.add('d-block');
    //increases the index onclick
    bio_index++;
  }
})
```

```css
.more {
  display: none;
}

.d-block {
  display: block;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="bio">
  <p>craftsman</p> *original display*
  <div class="more">
    <p>since birth has always had a love/hate relationship</p> *first readmore*
  </div>
  <div class="more">
    <p>She had half-survived blahblahblah.</p> *second readmore*
  </div>
  <button>Read more about craftsman</button>
</div>
```